# Synonym for: It may take longer than expected (ie. a meeting)

Tags: phrases, synonyms

For instance:

> I have a meeting today that is scheduled until 15h00 but it may take longer.

In dutch we would say: Het kan uitlopen.

How would I say this?

Comment: "it could drag on..." is common

Comment: @JoeBlow Why post a perfectly valid answer in a comment?

Comment: Hey Peter!  that's the cool thing to do these days :)  it sort of subverts the whole SO system, but supplies information.

Comment: 'It could overrun'. / '[W]e write stuff in comments that is too obvious to qualify for an answer.' [RegDwigнt] Though I think Joe is being too modest here.

Comment: If you say so... Either way, I'm happy to have my answer :-) Thanks Joe!

Comment: to prarphrase churchill, 'and has every reason to do so'

Comment: I thought answers got put in comments because it's the cheap way to get star billing.

Comment: I wonder how appropriate would this be: _"I have a meeting today that is scheduled until 15:00, **but it may still take a while**"_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Could run overtime* or *may extend past 3.00pm*, or as @Joe Blow said, *it could drag on*.

Comment: I find `it could drag on` to be a perfectly understandable expression. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I’d say the meeting might **run long.**

I am not able to find authoritative backing for this phrasing, but I assure you it is said around me and by me quite frequently. I work in an office in Chicago.

Answer (score 0):

If the extended time is likely to be short, you could say

> I have a meeting today that is scheduled until 15h00 *or [thereabouts](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/thereabouts)*.

[*Collins*]

Comment: When someone would say this to me I would think it could be shorter or longer. I want to express that it will probably take longer.

Comment: @Peter I don't disagree.